# mysql_query_rules defined in proxysql.cnf but not loaded

Tags: proxysql

My proxysql.cnf contains:

```
# ...
mysql_query_rules:
(
    {
        active = 1
        match_digest = "^SHOW.*"
        destination_hostgroup = 3
        apply = 0
    },
    {
        active = 1
        match_digest = "^SELECT.*"
        destination_hostgroup = 3
        apply = 0
    },
    {
        active = 1
        match_digest = "^SELECT.* FOR UPDATE"
        destination_hostgroup = 2
        apply = 1
    },
)

# ...
```

But when proxysql starts, the `mysql_query_rules` defintion is not loaded.

```
select * from mysql_query_rules;
Empty set (0.001 sec)
```

How to make proxysql loads the `mysql_query_rules` definition from the `proxysql.cnf` file at startup?

Answer (score 0):

The **rule_id** field is mandatory.

```
{
   rule_id=1
   active = 1
   match_digest = "^SHOW.*"
   destination_hostgroup = 3
   apply = 0
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the below-mentioned steps :

1. Insert into mysql_query_table
2. LOAD MYSQL QUERY RULES TO RUNTIME;
3. SAVE MYSQL QUERY RULES TO DISK;

After this your query will be persisted